# Como mudar os campos de autenticação do wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, login

Estava querendo em um tema qualquer, alterar para o usuario logar como se a senha fosse de um outro campo da mesma tabela. Só que desconheço do processo de login do wordpress

Comment: Que campo, por exemplo?

Comment: Por exemplo, o processo de login normal o sistema verifica a senha do campo "user_pass", certo? Queria fazer o sistema verificar um campo que criei, "user_cpf". Pro cara logar usando o nome de login só que a senha seria o proprio cpf dele.

Comment: Você pode tentar com o plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Comment: Qualquer coisa posso postar um código, mas preciso saber se esse campo foi criado na tabela ou você usou a função `add_user_meta` etc. Você também precisa está ciente que tem que fazer a verificação se o CPF já existe; etc. Ou você pode atualizar a tradução de "Nome de usuário" para "CPF"

Comment: Valdeir Psr > Cara se vc puder me ajudar com isso ficaria agradecido ;)
No primeiro momento criei o campo direto na tabela, agora ha pouco fiquei sabendo do user meta. No entanto eu qria um exemplo pratico simples fazendo essa verificação se o cara usar a senha ou o cpf